# From an SQLite database, given the complete DATETIME() stamp, how would I get entries based on the hour-component?

Tags: datetime, sqlite

I am saving complete DATETIME() strings to my SQLite database and now I am wondering how I can retrieve entries based on hours.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now') - strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2013-03-16 14:51:00')
```

Would calculate the difference in years for example (here `1`).

But when I am just getting the %H component, I would run into problems for cases like

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2013-03-15 14:51:00') - strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2013-03-16 14:51:00')
```

Which would return `0` instead of `24`, right. So how do I get the difference in hours given the complete datetime stamp most effectively?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to convert the datetime stamps to unix epoch `strtime('%s', ...)`, do the subtraction and then convert to hours, like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT (strftime('%s','2013-03-15 14:51:00') - strftime('%s','2013-03-16 14:51:00')) / 3600;
-24
```